# How to find a property which matches a regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an object with multiple attributes which are regular expressions, such as:

```
let a = {
   '/^\/a' : 'value 1',
   '/^\/b' : 'value 2',
   '/^\/d' : 'value 4',
}
```

What is the best way to get one of the properties that matches a specific string?

For instance, if trying to get `'/a'` should return me `'value 1'` while trying to get `'/c'` should return `undefined`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the use case is, and am suspicious that this is not the best way to go about it - but can't you just loop through the keys, make a Regex object out of each one in turn and test them against the given string? Then return the corresponding value of the first match, or `undefined` if you don't find a match.

Comment: This seems a bit like an [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you describe the purpose of this design choice?

Comment: The leading `/` in each of your regexps look wrong. Do you mean `^\/a` instead of `/^\/a`?

Comment: I'm trying to make an authorization component based on NodeJS Express router's patterns associated to groups. The idea is to have a middleware which verifies if the accessed route is in rules config and if it is, whether the user has access to it. My regex are more complex, such as: `"/^\/someRoute\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/someAction\/?$/i"`

Comment: the `/` characters are delimiters for RegExp literals. You don't actually need them as part of the regular expression. e.g. `/^\/a/` is equivalent to `new RegExp("^/a")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems odd, but here's one way you could write `lookup` -

```js
const data =
  { "^\/a": 'value1'
  , "^\/b": 'value2'
  , "^\/d": 'value3'
  }

const lookup = (str = "", o = {}) =>
  ( Object
      .entries (o)
      .find (([ k, _ ]) => (new RegExp (k)) .test (str))
      || []
  )
  [1]

console .log
  ( lookup ('/a', data) // value1
  , lookup ('/b', data) // value2
  , lookup ('/c', data) // undefined
  )
```

Comment: It's a pity though that with every lookup the regular expression objects have to be constructed.

Comment: @trincot agreed, I think the "tuples" in your answer is probably a better data format

Answer (score 2):

key/value pairs are not really useful here, because the key cannot be exploited: you might need to try *all* regexes before finding a match (or not). So you might as well use an array of pairs. This also has the advantage that you can store regex objects, while in the object you had to use string representations.

So here is how that would work:

```js
const regexes = [
   [/^\/a/, 'value 1'],
   [/^\/b/, 'value 2'],
   [/^\/d/, 'value 4'],
];

function getValue(s) {
    const i = regexes.findIndex(([regex]) => regex.test(s));
    if (i > -1) return regexes[i][1];
}

console.log(getValue("/b"));
```

Comment: This is exactly what the `Object.entries().find()` answer does, just without having to unwrap the object first or 'reconstitute' the regexes from keys. It's a bit cleaner and more idiomatic, in my opinion.